# Best practice for setting boolean flags

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight, ria

I'm looking for best practices in regards to having a class which has a flag which decides whether an operation can be performed on that class or not. This entire class will be returned in WCF REST services as well used in a Silverlight GUI via RIA Services in order to set certain action buttons to be enabled or disabled for the user. I want to know best practices for setting up a class in this way. For example:

```
public class SomeCustomerClass
{
    private bool _canResetCustomer;
    public bool CanResetCustomer
    {
        get { return _canResetCustomer; } //TODO: Place GET logic here from DB if it's null
        set { _canResetCustomer = value; }
    }

    if (this._canResetCustomer)
    {
        ResetCustomer();
    }
...
```

See my "TODO"? I need to determine if the bool has been set. If it hasn't been set, I need to get the eligibility of this customer for reset from a list of data-based rules from the database. The way I see it, there are two options, both of which I've used before:

1. Define another bool which tracks whether CanReset has been set or not, like so:

   ```
       public bool _canResetSet { get; set; }
   ```
2. Change my bool to a nullable type. I think in the constructor I'd have to instantiate the object with _canResetCustomer = null. Maybe?

Not sure why I'm asking this question except that maybe I'm just shy of nullable types. Does this entire dilemma speak to other issues with the way I design things? I commonly use this method of flagging in webforms applications as well.

Comment: This is pretty specific. I doubt there _is_ a "best practice".

Comment: Using nullables is fine, otherwise they wouldn't be in the language. You can of course consider some custom enum to reflect three states, but nullable here looks like a valid option

Comment: You said `DB` in the question. Nullable types where specifically made for that purpose IIRC.

Comment: You could use nullable bool or enum, but I would break the call to the database into a method and just set the bool to false by default.

Comment: I guess if I set it to false by default, how do I know if the object is dirty or not?

Comment: @JesseGood That is a good point!

Comment: When using `bool` values, I tend to design my code such that a default value of `false` will give me the behavior I am expecting.

Comment: Jon said the same thing... I'll re-ask the question:

How do you tell if the object is dirty or not? How do I know if the false, isn't really false, but just not-updated yet?

Comment: I am not sure why you are lazy-loading a boolean, can you enforce that it is populated initially? You do not want your WCF design to be to chatty, the latency will be much more expensive than the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with nullable. If its `HasValue`equals `false`, go check the db. Setting it to null in the constructor isn't necessary, as it is the default.

Comment: beat me by 30 seconds